# neo4j and java collection search

Tags: java, neo4j

Hi i'm trying to search using operator IN, but always return an empty list, what is wrong ? Bellow my unit test. Whta I want is to search a product by descriptio or a similarity word that macths description. (Futurely I pretend to implement fuzzy).

```
private GraphDatabaseService graph;
private Index<Node> indexProduct;
private ExecutionEngine engine;

@Before
public void prepareTestDatabase() {
    TestGraphDatabaseFactory testGraphDatabaseFactory = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory();
    this.graph = testGraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("/tmp/neo4j/tests");
    this.indexProduct = this.graph.index().forNodes("node_product");
    this.engine = new ExecutionEngine(this.graph, StringLogger.SYSTEM);
    this.loadDataForTest();
}

private void loadDataForTest() {
    Transaction tx = this.graph.beginTx();

    List<String> similarities = new ArrayList<>();
    similarities.add("televisor");
    similarities.add("tv");
    String description = "televisão";
    Product product = new Product(description, similarities);

    Node node = this.graph.createNode(DynamicLabel.label(product.description));
    node.setProperty("description", product.description);
    node.setProperty("similarities", product.similarities);

    this.indexProduct.add(node, "PRODUCT", product.description);

    tx.success();
    tx.finish();
}

@Test
public void searchByDescription(){
    String description = "televisão";

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutionResult result = this.engine.execute("start n=node:node_product('PRODUCT:*') WHERE HAS(n.similarities) AND n.similarities IN ['tv'] return n.description");
    for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
        for (Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet()) {
            Object value = column.getValue();
            list.add(String.valueOf(value));
        }
    }

    Assert.assertTrue(list.contains(description));
}
```

This is Product class

```
class Product {
    String description;
String[] similarities;

Product(String description, List<String> similaritiesList) {
    super();
    this.description = description;
    this.similarities = new String[similaritiesList.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<similaritiesList.size(); i++)
        this.similarities[i] = similaritiesList.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got your usecase right. But I think there's a little confusion in your Cypher query.
Your query:

```
"start n=node:node_product('PRODUCT:*') WHERE HAS(n.similarities) AND n.similarities IN ['tv'] return n.description"
```

Lets have a look on `n.similarities IN ['tv']`. The property `similarities` is an array. `['tv']` is an an array of strings. Thus, the expression `` `n.similarities IN ['tv'] `` always evaluates to `false` because `['tv']` does not contain any arrays, let alone the `similarities` array.

In the end I just figure you meant something else, viz.

```
 'tv' IN n.similarities
```

Could this be right? You want to check whether the string `tv` is contained in the `similarities` array. When I change the query that way, i.e. the resulting query would be

```
start n=node:node_product('PRODUCT:*') WHERE HAS(n.similarities) AND 'tv' IN n.similarities return n.description
```

then, the adapted test class works for me.